# How do I read in an input file with a scanner or buffered reader and count all the occurences of a specific character in the input file

Tags: java

How can I read in a file with a scanner or bufferedreader and count all of the letter "B" in the file?

Right now I am taking in the file with a scanner and I have an int to count up every time I run into a "B", as well as an int to count up in order to check the next character in the string, but it only works for the first line because, when j reaches 13 I get an out of bounds exception(the input file has 13 characters on each line, then a line break).

```
while (input.hasNext() == true) {
if (input.next().charAt(j) == 'B') {
b++;
}
j++;
}
```

I've tried splitting on whitespace, but it tells me there are zero "B"s every time, which isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to solve this solution is to set the delimiter of your Scanner:

```
input.useDelimiter("");
```

Then, whenever the next token is equal to "B", increment your counter:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    if (input.next().equals("B"))
        b++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int count;
while(input.hasNext())
{
String line=input.next();
getCount(line);
}

private static int getCount(String line)
{
char[] arr=line.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
if(arr[i]=='B')
count ++;
}
}
```

finally count will .have total number of 'B'

Answer (score 0):

I think the [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) [**.countMatches method**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is what you're looking for, you can use it like this:

```
int occurences=0;
while(input.hasNext())
{
   String line=input.next();
   occurences+=StringUtils.countMatches(line, "B");
}
System.out.println("There are "+occurences+" occurences of the character B in the file.");
```